# Block identity matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

Let us consider the matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{2N \times 2N}$ defined as 
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix} I & I+\Lambda_{12} \\ I + \Lambda_{21} & I\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix, and the linear system
\begin{equation}
A\begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $v_1$, $v_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are vectors of $\mathbb R^N$. Assume that $\Lambda_{12}$ and $\Lambda_{21}$ are tridiagonal and such that $A$ is invertible.

Is it possible to derive a bound on $\|v_1 - v_2\|$ as a function of $\|\Lambda_{12}\|$, $\|\Lambda_{21}\|$, $\|\Lambda_{12} \pm \Lambda_{21}\|$ (or their inverses) and $\|b_1 - b_2\|$? If yes, under which conditions?

**Update: Case $N = 1$**

In the case $N = 1$ it is possible to find explicitly
\begin{align}
v_1 &= \frac1{\det A}(b_1-(1+\Lambda_{12})b_2)\\
v_2 &= \frac1{\det A}(b_2-(1+\Lambda_{21})b_1),
\end{align}
where $\det A = -(\Lambda_{12} + \Lambda_{21} + \Lambda_{12}\Lambda_{21})$. After a couple of applications of the triangle inequality, one gets
\begin{equation}
|v_1 - v_2| \leq \frac{(2+|\Lambda_{12}|)\,|b_1-b_2|+|\Lambda_{12} - \Lambda_{21}|\, |b_1|}{|\det A|}.
\end{equation}
Does this generalize to higher dimensions ?

Comment: In general we will have $\det A = \det[-(\Lambda_{12} + \Lambda_{21} + \Lambda_{12}\Lambda_{21})]$, though I'm not sure about generalizing the rest of your analysis

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom, I found the answer in the end. The generalization was not 100% trivial. If you are interested, it is given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. Finding $v_1$ and $v_2$ by substitution, and doing a couple of triangle inequalities, one finds
\begin{align}
\|v_1 - v_2\| &\leq \|Q_2^{-1} \|\,\|\Lambda_{12}-\Lambda_{21}\|\,\|b_2\|
 + \|Q_2^{-1} - Q_1^{-1}\|\,\|\Lambda_{21}\|\,\|b_1\| \\
&\quad + \|Q_2^{-1}+Q_1^{-1}+Q_2^{-1}\Lambda_{21}\|\,\|b_2-b_1\|,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
Q_1 &= \Lambda_{21}+\Lambda_{12}+\Lambda_{21}\Lambda_{12}, \\
Q_2 &= \Lambda_{21}+\Lambda_{12}+\Lambda_{12}\Lambda_{21}.
\end{align}
Note that in case $N = 1$, we have $Q_1 = Q_2$ and therefore this bound reduces to the one given in the question itself. Moreover, working a bit more, one gets 
$$
\|Q_2^{-1} - Q_1^{-1}\| \leq \|\Lambda_{12}\Lambda_{21} - \Lambda_{21}\Lambda_{12} \|\,\|Q_1^{-1}\|\,\|Q_2^{-1}\|,
$$
which may (or may not) be more explicit.